# Find the general value of $\theta$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, systems-of-equations

> Find the general value of $\theta$ which satisfies the equation $(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)(\cos3\theta+i\sin3\theta)\dots \{\cos(2n-1)\theta+i\sin(2n-1)\theta\}=1$.

**My attempt**:

$(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)(\cos3\theta+i\sin3\theta)\dots \{\cos(2n-1)\theta+i\sin(2n-1)\theta\}$

$=\cos\{\theta+3\theta+\dots+(2n-1)\theta\}+i\sin\{\theta+3\theta+\dots+(2n-1)\theta\}$

$=\cos(n^2\theta)+i\sin(n^2\theta)$

$\therefore \cos(n^2\theta)+i\sin(n^2\theta)=1$

Equating real and imaginary parts, we get,

$\cos(n^2\theta)=1$ and $\sin(n^2\theta)=0$

$\therefore n^2\theta=2k\pi$ and $n^2\theta=k\pi$

How to proceed further? Does $\theta$ have to simultaneously satisfy both the equations or only $n^2\theta=2k\pi?$

Comment: If $\theta$ satisfies the first equation, it satisfies the second. The converse is not true.

Comment: Is the cosine of a sum equal to the sum of the cosines?

Comment: @Bernard, I do not get why. Can you please explain?

Comment: @ChrisLeary, I do not think so.

Comment: An even multiple of $\pi$ is a multiple of $\pi$. Conversely, not all multiples of $\pi$ are even multiples.

Comment: But then the two equations are not satisfied for the same value of $k$.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the complex exponential, $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$? If so, the equation becomes $e^{in^2\theta}=1$, which implies $n^2\theta$ is an integer multiple of $2\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the equation is same:
$$e^{i\theta(1+3+\cdots+2n-1)}=e^{i2\pi k}$$